# How to implement get photo from camera instead of getting gallary in Ionic cordova with angularJs

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

How to using native keypad and native camera listener functions

Answer (score 1):

Refer this link -

http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/camera/

while using this plugin set sourceType as CAMERA

eg.

```
sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
```